# Mouse Event in Actionscript2?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, mouseevent

I have a problem getting mouse events in Flash Actionscript 2.

Here is what I have so far :

```
var _mouseListener:Object = new Object();
_mouseListener.onMouseClick = Delegate.create(this, Mouse_Event);   
Mouse.addListener(_mouseListener);


private function Mouse_Event():Void
{
 trace("Mouse_Event mouse handled");
}
```

I have the same setup for the key handling and there it works, but not for the mouse.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, fixed it with this

```
_level0.onMouseUp =  Delegate.create(this, onMouse_Event);
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using "_level0" notation I've recently used:

> this.onMouseDown = Delegate.create(this, onMouseDown_Event);